# How to prevent frame injection (clickjacking) in java application?

Tags: java, jsp, iframe, code-injection, clickjacking

How can we prevent frame injection in Java application?

Like in a Penetration testing, 
it is found that if a hacker drafts a demo html page, 
and inside that page he has used iframe, 
which has the URL of the working application, 
he/she can see the data through that URL/request(created in an iframe).

suppose this is the hackers file, test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\"   \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head><body>
<iframe id="inner" src="http://hostname:8080/Application_Name/ABC/DEF/SomePage.jsp?ABC=QWERTYL&XYZ=1&CDE=24" width="600" height="400" scrolling="yes">

</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

And now the hacker is able to retrieve the data within the application. How to stop this?

Comment: Please share your code to illustrate your question. This makes it a lot easier to answer the question.

Answer (score 7):

This is clickjacking attack: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking
The simpliest way to prevent it is to add header "X-Frame-Options" with value "DENY". This can be done using [filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). Register it in your web.xml and use code like this:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
    response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");    
    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
}
```

All modern browsers support this header, but to protect users with legacy browsers you will need also defensive javascript in the UI. More details: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: The application I am working on has frames, so will DENY block it even working normally?

Comment: Yes, "DENY" will disable all frames (even from the same site). So in your case you will need value "SAMEORIGIN" (it allows your site to frame the content). But there is a tricky part when your frame uses another frame - then configuration become more complex (see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Limitations_2)

Comment: Yes, I tried with "DENY", then application itself wasn't able to work. Using "SAMEORIGIN"  does block the attack, The IE says : "Following page cannot be displayed in frame". But when I click on: "Open this content in new window", the data still opens. So, I am still having the partial Issue.